# Android screen forms not updating

Tags: android, xml

I am having an unusual problem with an Android form. The form displays and works correctly, however, the screen updates to not seem to be happening. So when you untick a check box, it appears to be ticked, as the screen doesn't clear.

The code is:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        }
}
```

And the XML Layout (a bit long I'm afraid, as I'm not sure what's relevant):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/saveOriginalImage"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/saveOriginalImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/saveDirectory"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/saveDirectory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textUri" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sendOriginalImage"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/sendOriginalImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        style="@style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ok"
                style="@style/ButtonBarButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/OK" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I've been scratching my head over it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

modify AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
</activity>
```

if its not work let me know.
i give another solution

Comment: handle screen orentation programically

Comment: I do not want to rotate the screen. Screen rotation forces a screen refresh, which then looks correct

Comment: 'android:screenOrientation="portrait"'

Comment: What effect will that have? Do you understand the problem?